# Dynamically created content on Android - retrieve friends newest posts

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm trying to create this:

[image: example]

It goes through your friends, finds the ones with new posts and retrieves them. What's the logic that would go behind something like this? What should I be trying to do?

Comment: you can call the api in an interval.

Comment: Your application connect to your own feed service?

Comment: @Sergey Pretty much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two popular way to deliver news to receivers.

### First way

Receiver asking for news from *friends* with a certain frequency. In this case server works as mediator for senders and receivers. Client application asking for news from paticular *friend* application. For this architecture typically used *Mediator* pattern:

[image: Mediator]

### Second way

Source of news sends this to server. Server works as observer and sends news directly to receivers with online state. Otherwise, server collects news for particular user (client application) in queue. For this behaviour typically used *Observer* pattern:

[image: Observer]

For more information about architecture templates see [source PDF](http://www.mcdonaldland.info/files/designpatterns/designpatternscard.pdf)